# How to stop cron from mailing me?

Tags: 12.10, php, cron, smtp

I have setup a ssmtp server with my gmail username and password.

After that i have been getting constant emails from my laptop to my gmail.

Here the mails.

The first one is somewhat like this:

The Subject is

> Cron  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -ignore_readdir_race -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete

The sender is 
root

The body of the text is

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/msql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/msql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

The Second mail is:
Subject:

> Anacron job 'cron.daily' on Innovator

Body is:

> /etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
>   apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
>   /etc/cron.daily/update-notifier-common:
>   flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.270.orig.tar.gz
>   Installing from local file /tmp/tmphjHyVl.gz
>   Flash Plugin installed.

When I look in /etc/cron.d there are two files:
anacron php5

The contents of php5 are as follows.

```
# /etc/cron.d/php5: crontab fragment for php5
#  This purges session files older than X, where X is defined in seconds
#  as the largest value of session.gc_maxlifetime from all your php.ini
#  files, or 24 minutes if not defined.  See /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime

# Look for and purge old sessions every 30 minutes
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -ignore_readdir_race -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
```

The contents of anacron filea are as follows:

```
# /etc/cron.d/anacron: crontab entries for the anacron package

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

30 7    * * *   root    start -q anacron || :
```

I have also tried adding the string >/dev/null 2>&1 at the end of the php file (as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390590/phantom-cron-job-after-installing-ssmtp-for-sending-e-mails)) but still i get the mails.

How do i stop from getting the mails.

Comment: See if this helps: http://askubuntu.com/q/247348/25656

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: do `dpkg --purge php5-sybase`.

Longer answer: Debian packages have split conffiles and the rest.  When you remove the package (and not purge) the conffiles (such as /etc/php5/conf.d/mssql.ini) remains in the place and php5 then tries to load non-existent library.  This was fixed in php5 5.4.0, but it will be fixed only in non-removed packages (obviously one cannot fix a bug in the package where only conffiles remain).

Answer (score 1):

Try this go to.

```
 sudo crontab -e
```

then put this line above your cronjob.

```
MAILTO=""
```

save and Exit.