# This anacron cron job is sending emails to me - how can I redirect the output to null?

Tags: cron, anacron

```
$ cat update-notifier-common 
#!/bin/sh

set -e

[ -x /usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader ] || exit 0

# Try to rerun any package data downloads that failed at package install time.
/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader
```

What modifications should I do here to avoid the output being emailed to me every week?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247348/stop-cron-from-mailing-the-user)

Comment: Thx! Have added MAILTO="" and will see how it goes ...

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding `MAILTO=`, after which cron won't send any emails at all, end the crontab entry with  `> /dev/null 2>&1`. This limits the scope of the "be quiet" to the entry that it ends with...

Comment: I understand that. Both ways achieve the same result I guess.

Comment: IMHO there's a huge difference between not getting any email output from **any** crontab entry and not getting email output from a **single** entry.